# ls first file of given type from given directory

Tags: bash, ls

This searches only in the `pwd`, despite having specified the directory. Probably caused by the third argument.

```
supported="*mov *mp4"
ls /home/kv/m $supported | head -1
```

..Removing the filter brings up the first file found by `ls`, but what can I use to tell `ls` to consider only the file types listed in $supported? --It's worth mentioning that the extensions mustn't be case-sensitive.

```
ls /home/kv/m | head -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls /home/kv/m | grep -i -E '\.(mov|mp4)$' | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it in a subshell, and `cd` to the directory first

```
first=$( cd /home/kv/m && ls $supported | head -1 )
```

you might want to `shopt -s nullglob` first, in case there are not .mov or .mp4 files.